# How to add constraint in a optimal control design?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, control-theory, numerical-optimization, optimal-control

When I do my project, I need add a constraint to the trajectory in a certain time within nonlinear optimal control design. For example, there are two dimensional system , x and y. I would like to set x(3) = 5 and y(3) = 6 (the time interval is [0, 5]s), which mean I want the trajectory travel (5, 6) at 3 second.

Is there any way to formulate that ?

If there are some papers or materials can be recommends , that would be great.

thanks

Jie

Comment: What optimization method are you using, Pontryagin's maximum principle?

Comment: I take the numerical method to solve it. Interior Point Method.